# Откуда пошло слово "совок", подразумевающее "Советский Союз"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, жаргон

В одной из [серий](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NipHC1PLx4) "Benny Hill's show" (год сказать трудно, но это явно было во времена СССР и Брежнева) происходит интересная сцена, где человек переворачивает первые три буквы слова SOWCOW, и таким образом получается MOSCOW.
Хотелось бы понять, слово "совок" нам подкинули британцы, или британцы позаимствовали это слово у нас, для своей супер-шуточки SOWCOW -> MOSCOW?

Comment: Пробовал перевернуть... Ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, сначала появилось понятие ***Homo sovieticus.*** Как говорил писатель Геллер, было объявлено, что СССР стал царством свободы, родиной нового, высшего типа человека разумного — Хомо Советикус. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_Soveticus

Но на западе черты нового человека стали воспринимать уже негативно, поэтому сленговое слово ***совок*** пришлось весьма кстати. Сначала оно обозначало **вещи**, изготовленные в СССР, а потом уже страну и советских людей.
Материал из Интернета на эту тему https://periskop.livejournal.com/1538192.html

Для  образования слова ***совок*** (советский — совок) используется суффикс ОК широкого профиля: с его помощью можно было обозначать как предметы, так и и лица, отнесенные к действию или признаку (играть — игрок, звонить — звонок, дикий — дичок).

Но особый смысл был в том, что весьма прозаическое слово ***совок*** уже существовало в русском языке (совать — совок), надо было только придать ему соответствующее значение.

**Из словаря**

1. **СОВОК**,  м. Лопатка с загнутыми кверху краями и короткой ручкой; приспособление, имеющее форму такой лопатки. Железный с. С. для мусора. С. для муки.  С-ая лопата.
2. **СОВОК**, -а; м. Презрит. 1. [с прописной буквы] О Советском Союзе, Советской власти. Жить в Совке. 2. О том, у кого сильны привычки и навыки, сложившиеся в условиях господства коммунистической идеологии.

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что _совок_ от _советский_, а не от _Советский Союз_? Почему не универбация?

Comment: Сложно сказать, с каким значением  слово было образовано вначале, но в любом случае схема образования нестандартная, с усечением основы.

Answer (score 1):

Я со всей ответственностью могу заявить, что слово сие слышал еще при советской власти - и даже далеко не в последние годы её.

Не думаю, что его отцом мог стать какой-то конкретный автор, даже конкретный человек. Папа ему - народ.

Признаю, свойство моей памяти таково, что многие знакомые вещи (слова - особенно) кажутся мне гораздо более старыми, чем на самом деле (или чем это можно заключить из всякого рода современных источников). Но тут я просто не могу ошибиться, ибо слышал его регулярно начиная едва ли не с конца шестидесятых годов. Я с детства крутился в среде, где взрослые были "выездными", сам побывал в Монголии, которая хоть и "не заграница", но все ж чуть ближе к ней, чем деревня Гадюкино. Тогда еще этот "совок" не нес резко негативной оценки, это было просто ироническое обозначение издалека горячо любимой родины (sic! здесь - со строчной).

Answer (score 0):

Я помню старую телепередачу, в которой певец и композитор Александр Градский в компании друзей говорил о своём авторстве на это слово. Но вполне вероятно, что независимым образом оно могло прийти в голову и другим скептикам - слово напрашивалось.

Answer (score 0):

Из Циклопедии:

> Возможное происхождение термина
>   Музыкант Александр Градский неоднократно заявлял, что термин «совок» придумал именно он, причём в качестве объяснительно-ласкательного термина, по его словам — «как объяснение безысходности и бессмысленности борьбы, попытка, как сказать, пригласить к разведению рук». Согласно Градскому, это произошло, когда он с товарищами решил распить спиртные напитки на улице, не имея при этом рюмок или стаканов. Так как прямо из горла пить не хотелось, они были заменены удачно обнаруженными детскими формочками, забытыми в песочнице. При этом Градскому достался совок для песка.[2][3]
>   Существует версия о происхождении слова «совок» от аббревиатуры «советский оккупант» (в Прибалтике, в среде националистического подполья).

http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3)

А вот еще:

> ...на авторство этого слова претендуют сразу несколько человек. Первый в очереди – известный музыкант Александр Градский. Он с друзьями как-то выпивал в песочнице. Рюмками друзьям служили забытые детьми пластмассовые формочки, а самому Градскому достался совочек.
>   Писатель и философ Михаил Эпштейн в подтверждение авторства ссылается на свою книгу «Великая Совь» (название образовано по аналогии со словом «Русь»), героев которой он нарек «совками» и «совщицами». В 1989 г. автор читал ее по Би-би-си, откуда обидное прозвище могло просочиться в СССР.
>   Наконец, у «совков» есть и коллективный автор – культурологи Александр Генис и Петр Вайль. Они утверждали, что придумали это слово для обозначения советских туристов, выезжающих в социалистические страны.

[Совки и другие. К истории и значению слова «совок»](http://www.topos.ru/article/6455)

Comment: Я это всё читал, и видел. Но мне как-то не нравится версия. Получается, Бенни Хилл в своём шоу, взял и начал смешить англичан словом SOWCOW->MOSCOW?

Comment: Я уверен, что не было единственного автора, как и то, что английская версия происхождения - полная реникса. Версия "аббревиатура чего-то" - не о _происхождении_, а об использовании по местной надобности уже существовавшего.

Comment: О каких рюмках речь, если стаканы были в каждом автомате? А пить из формочки, — ну этож ниже всякого достоинства.

Comment: Возможно, происходит также от диссидентских эвфемизмов: Софья Власьевна, сова .... ну и "Победоносцев над Россией простёр совиные крыла"

Answer (score 0):

Я всегда считал, что значение "Советский Союз” для *совка* исходное, а "советские вещи" и "советские люди" — производные, как, например, "деревня" означает и деревенских жителей, и все деревенское. Обратное развитие нетипично  для языка.

Answer (score 0):

Первое упоминание в КРЯ слова *совок* в значении советский человек: «Я, разумеется, совок. Но ведь и они совки». [Владимир Маканин. Стол, покрытый сукном и с графином посередине (1993)].

Первое упоминание этого слова в значении Советский Союз: «Не люблю оперировать с валютой на территории Совка…». [Борис Левин. Инородное тело (1965—1994)].

Если не найдется свидетельств более раннего употребления слова «совок» в этих значениях, то приоритет в авторстве придется отдать В. Пелевину.

«До площади Санделя, где находился совком, идти надо было вниз по Спинномозговой. [Виктор Пелевин. День бульдозериста (1991)].

Текст этого произведения насыщен словами-новообразованиями в т.ч. "непрямого обозначения". Авторское сокращение «совком» пародирует привычные *парт-*, *проф-*, *горкомы*. Очевидной кажется и издевка, заключающаяся в полном совпадении с формой слова *совок* в тв. падеже.